# Acessing Christianity SE on the go

Tags: discussion

I’ve found this application that lets you access Christianity SE on your android phone – 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.droidstack&hl=ru

The repository can be browsed using Mercurial at – 
https://code.google.com/p/droidstack/

So far it is looking good. Doesn’t offer all the features of SE portal but is simple and doesn't contain any bloat.

Don’t know if it’s appropriate to do this but just wanted to put it here so that more people can be aware of it.

If you have any such utilities or tips - software or otherwise - please share them below.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of additional ways of accessing the site though third party programs or modifying the browsing experience are noted on StackExchange's own third party extension site:

### https://stackapps.com/

Since all the SE sites share the same API and engine, tools written for any site are usually applicable to all of them. You might find a few that are much more specific to out site such as the [Bible Gateway Markdown Generator](https://stackapps.com/q/2992/3583) user script.

Unfortunately the API is read-only, so none of the available third party programs can be used to vote, author posts or otherwise interact with the site. Fortunately, the normal mobile website version is pretty solid.